# Limiting Memory of Snap Packages

Tags: snap, cgroup, slack

Some snaps (cough Slack) will given the opportunity eat up an almost unlimited amount of memory. In the pre-slack post systemd world I could create a namespace, limit it's memory/cpu etc... and force slack to not eat the world by executing it inside of that namespace.

What's the proper way to add a similar limit to a Snap Package? Since snaps are already exectuted inside of some cgroup wizardry I'm hoping its as simple as a `snap modify <snappackage> -addmemlimit 1G` or something.

Comment: Whatever answer you receive, please also remember to file a bug report with the developers of that snap. They didn't intend to build a memory hog.

Comment: How does one file a bug for a snap? I know how to do it for a deb but I'm not sure with a snap.

Comment: One way is to go through the Snap Store and look for the "Contact Slack" link. Another way is to try the snapcraft forum and see if a Slack rep hangs out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but experimental, through the use of the *quota groups* feature. You have to create a quota group with resource limits (for now, only the memory resource limit is available), and attach one or more snaps to that quota group :

1. Enable the experimental feature : `snap set system experimental.quota-groups=true`
2. Create the quota group w/snaps attached : `snap set-quota --memory=4GB memlimit firefox`

Source : https://snapcraft.io/docs/quota-groups

**EDIT :**
Now that it’s not an experimental feature any more, the documentation states that quota groups apply to *snap services only*.

Hence people who want to limit system resource access of, say, Firefox, should use `setrlimit()` to limit e.g. the process’ data segment size. Non-programmatic ways of doing this include :

- Using the bash primitive `ulimit` to set limit(s) on the shell process, all programs launched from that shell inheriting the limit(s). For example, limiting the data segment size to 4  GiB : `ulimit -d 4194304`
- Using the `prlimit` command to launch the program, with the same purpose. With still the same example of a 4 GiB data segment size limit : `prlimit -d=4294967296 firefox`

Another option is to directly use the same system snaps use : cgroups (v2 in the case of snaps).

Comment: Glad to see this drop. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Christopher : Except that it works for snap services only ! At least now that it’s out of experimental. So one has to resort to other methods, like either using cgroups directly, or good old `setrlimit()` to set a realtime limit on e.g. the process data segment